# How do I work around deprecated properties/methods with (possibly non-object) arguments?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My goal is to achieve compatibility across 3.x SDK versions for UIImagePickerController and it's `allows(Image)Editing` property.

```
// SDK 2.0 to 3.0
myImagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = YES;

// SDK 3.1
myImagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Some research reveals some objective-c approaches, but **what is considered best practice for handling deprecated methods?**

1. [`performSelector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904515/how-to-use-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-primitive-types-in-cocoa) or `NSInvocation` for non-object arguments
2. [`#define`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820142/how-to-target-a-specific-iphone-version/823287#823287) approach
3. Any other recommended strategies...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSString * key = @"allowsEditing";
if ([myImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsImageEditing:)]) {
  key = @"allowsImageEditing";
}
[myImagePickerController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:key];
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Great answer. I'll put that one under #3 :)

Answer (score -1):

wrap them in a `@try @catch` block to ensure a working feature regardless of a deprecated method.

Comment: s/depreciated/deprecated/  ;-)

Comment: Exceptions in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch should only be used for non-recoverable errors.