# in objective-c, sleep happens before code prior to it

Tags: objective-c

In this code, it seems the sleep happens before the hiding of a button. Why is that?

```
-(void)buttonPressed{
        NSLog(@"Button pressed!");
        button.hidden=true;
        sleep(rand()%10);
        NSLog(@"out of sleep!");
    }
```

Comment: What environment is this - other than "objective-c"? Most likely OSX or iOS?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by suspending the main thread for a random number of seconds?

Answer (score 8):

The setting of 'hidden' happens immediately and triggers a `SetNeedsDisplay` that goes on the run loop. Then the method sleeps. Then after the sleep the run loop executes and the display is updated. So it is just that the sleep prevents the display from being updated until the sleep is over.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `hidden` property was successfully set, but the screen wasn't updated, because you paused the thread.

Screen update will happen later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific objective-c knowledge on this point - but it is a common case that UI is single threaded and that the update of your button state is put on a queue for execution. The call to sleep then suspends all current thread activity and therefore halts UI updating.

Answer (score 0):

SetNeedsDisplay essentially sets a flag that will cause the control to be re-rendered the next time around the UI loop.  It won't take effect immediately, as it usually it delayed slightly so that various UI refreshes can be coalesced.

Performing a sleep() call in a UI thread is really frowned upon... if you're looking to perform some action n ms after hiding your button, I would recommend calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, as per this thread:

> [How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with primitive types in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904515/how-to-use-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-primitive-types-in-cocoa)

In general, you want to have the UI thread block as little as possible, as any blocking code (e.g. sleep) will cause the UI to lag, be generally unresponsive, or beach-ball (SPoD).