# How to detect if any external libraries are calling [UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]?

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier, udid, uidevice

So, [since Apple is now rejecting apps that access UDID](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/03/21/after-a-year-of-warnings-apple-will-no-longer-accept-any-apps-that-use-udids-as-of-may-1st/), on our company's current project, we need to eliminate all APIs that make a call to this property:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

We have eliminated all the calls in our own code, but need to be sure that the many external libraries we are using are not making calls to this property.

What is the most reliable method for determining if a library is calling on this property?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the external libraries open source?

Comment: Most of the libraries are not open source.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9894190/440060

Comment: Check this answer,  Tips i got from Apple

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449182/itunes-app-submission-invalid-binary-issues/16514820#16514820

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aside from using `otx` (which seems to have gotten flaky) one option is to set a symbolic breakpoint on that method and then run the app for a while and see if you hit it.

Configuring a symbolic breakpoint for that method would look like this:

[image]

If you ever hit that breakpoint, you can find out who called it by opening the debugger console and typing `bt`. In this case the call came from my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but it works no matter who called it:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x001f4690 UIKit`-[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier], stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x001f4690 UIKit`-[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]
frame #1: 0x0000212e MyApp`-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](self=0x0747fcb0, _cmd=0x005aec21, application=0x08366300, launchOptions=0x00000000) + 702 at AppDelegate.m:37
frame #2: 0x00015157 UIKit`-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 266
frame #3: 0x00015747 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1248
frame #4: 0x0001694b UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 805
frame #5: 0x00027cb5 UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1022
frame #6: 0x00028beb UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
frame #7: 0x0001a698 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
frame #8: 0x01f01df9 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 339
frame #9: 0x01f01ad0 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 46
frame #10: 0x01f1bbf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
frame #11: 0x01f1b962 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
frame #12: 0x01f4cbb6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2118
frame #13: 0x01f4bf44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
frame #14: 0x01f4be1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #15: 0x0001617a UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 774
frame #16: 0x00017ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
frame #17: 0x00001d42 MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3f8) + 130 at main.m:16
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great!  The only problem with this, I suppose, is that it can only catch it if it actually calls the function, and not if it has the **potential** to call it.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for this!! It saved us potentially 1 week by helping us catch a library that we missed!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Quinn's answer:

- `strings` lists all the symbols in a compiled object or library, in order of first appearance per class. If you see `uniqueIdentifier` in the output, it's possible that they're calling some other method with that name. But if you see `currentDevice` in the output immediately followed by `uniqueIdentifier`, then they're almost certainly calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`. It's possible that the two lines would not be sequential, if the library is calling `currentDevice` earlier in the file.
- `otool -ov` lists all the classes, methods, and imports in the library. If it lists `uniqueIdentifier`, that likely means the library is defining its own method with that name. Look at the reference in context. At the bottom of each class you'll see a section like `Contents of (__DATA,__objc_classrefs) section` that lists the imports. If `_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice` is listed among the imports for the class you found referencing `uniqueIdentifier`, then there's a good chance that class is calling `-[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]`.
- The output of `nm` is similar to `otool` for this purpose. Specifically, it won't show you calls to `uniqueIdentifier`, but it will show you what classes import `UIDevice`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be difficult to reliably determine if a closed-source library is actually calling a method, but there are some ways you can see if they *might* be:

- Using [strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/strings.1.html) to see if "uniqueIdentifier" appears in the library, regardless of how it's used:

  `$ strings libFoo.a | grep uniqueIdentifier`
- Using [nm](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) or [otool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16514820/120292))
- Using [otx](http://otx.osxninja.com) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9894190/120292))

These approaches can help turn up potential invocations that setting a breakpoint may miss.