# iOS postpone screen update until next user interaction

Tags: ios, uiview

I need to postpone a screen update until next user interaction.  Although the code has changed the display, but I want it to be shown a bit later, will it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the NSObject method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

As all objects derive from NSObject, you can use the above method on *all* objects.
For example look here: [How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with primitive types in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904515/how-to-use-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-primitive-types-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to postpone something since the introduction of ARC is use GCD dispatch_after function.

```
double delayInSeconds = <#time#>;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
        });
```

This is a copy of the snippet already present in Xcode. 
Using this function you post pone any methods that you put inside the predefined zone.
Screen updates are controlled by system and you can't postpone them, but can postpone the method that will change data onscreen.