# When assign a weak variable to a strong variable

Tags: ios

When I reading SDWebImage source code, I found a snippet

```
if (url)
{
    __weak UIButton *wself = self;
    id<SDWebImageOperation> operation = [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadWithURL:url options:options progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
    {
        __strong UIButton *sself = wself;
        if (!sself) return;
        if (image)
        {
            [sself setBackgroundImage:image forState:state];
        }
        if (completedBlock && finished)
        {
            completedBlock(image, error, cacheType);
        }
    }];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &operationKey, operation, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

It is easy to understand that for avoiding the retain cycle, it uses __weak keyword for the self, however, why it assigns wself to a strong variable sself, won't the block be still retain the self.

Comment: Why not use self directly ?

Comment: @Danyun `self` is an strong but it is out of the block scope, so the block will retain it. `sself` is strong but it is in the block scope, it will be released at the end of the block, so no circle.

Comment: @KudoCC It sound reasonable. I will accept it if you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is an strong but it is out of the block scope, so the block will retain it. `sself` is strong but it is in the block scope, it will be released at the end of the block, so no circle.

BTW the correct answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018456/ios-blocks-and-strong-weak-references-to-self) is a good explanation about the block circle.