# Objective C arrow (->) pointer safety

Tags: objective-c

To avoid capturing of 'self' in a block, we often use a weak pointer. However, for some 'non-property' ivars (otherValue in this example):

```
@implementation MyClass
{
    NSString *otherValue;
}
```

We need a strong ref and an arrow accessor (->) usually done like:

```
MyClass *blockself = weakself;
blockself->otherValue
```

The problem is, accessing `blockself->otherValue` will crash if `blockself` is nil.

I can check for `if (blockself)`, but it 'can' be release right after, in the next line.

Example:

```
__weak MyClass *weakself = self;

[serverManager runSomething:^(Result *res) {

    // If pointer (weakself) is released, no problem. Accessing though a 'property'
    if (weakself.value) {

    }

    // For local iVars though:

    MyClass *blockself = weakself;

    // This will crash if 'blockself' is nil
    if (blockself->otherValue) {

    }

    // Can test for nil here

    if (blockself) {

        // But..
        // Potentiall, the pointer 'could' be released here

        if (blockself->_value) {

        }

    }
```

So, is the only safer way is to migrate from iVars to use a `@property`? Is there a 'safe' way to access iVars thought an arrow (`->`) accessor?

Comment: The point of capturing strongly in the block is to prevent the release of said object.

In our code, we avoid using `->` entirely.  Just use the property directly.  The reference to blockSelf will keep the object alive.

Comment: @bbum Your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938439/does-assigning-a-weak-pointer-to-a-strong-pointer-copy-the-object Pretty much clears it.

Comment: I'm confused a little, why crash at `->`? what's the detailed crash?

Comment: @Itachi `nil->value` will crash.

Comment: If the `weakself` is nil before assigning to `blockself`, ```if (blockself && blockself->otherValue)``` should be safe. If the `weakself` is not nil before that, then `blockself` make the original object's retained count increased by 1, `blockself` won't be released until the containing block get executed.

Comment: @Itachi It makes sense to assign `blockself` only if 'weakself' in not nil. Although, I think that the block context is not 'expected' to continue executing in such context (a view that was released for example). But yes, if `blockself` is assigned a non nil, it will hold it for the block scope.