# Different results of NSNumber to BOOL between iOS simulator and device in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, boolean, nsnumber

When I try to run the following code by iOS simulator (8.1 and 7.1), the value of "going" in myMethod is YES.

But when I use my iPhone (8.1.2) to run, the value of "going" will become NO.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]  afterDelay:0.5f];

- (void) myMethod:(BOOL)going {

  if (going) {
     // do something
  }
  else {
     // do another thing
  }
}
```

I cannot find the root cause of getting different results.

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: [How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with primitive types in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/904515)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myMethod:` takes a `BOOL`. not an `NSNumber`. You need the following:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:@YES afterDelay:0.5f];

- (void)myMethod:(NSNumber *)going {
    if ([going boolValue]) {
       // do something
    } else {
       // do another thing
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use `dispatch_after` instead of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self myMethod:YES];
});

- (void)myMethod:(BOOL)going {
    if (going) {
       // do something
    } else {
       // do another thing
    }
}
```