# why the value 'NO' is accepted as object while 'YES' is not

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is the code I'm playing around, where I need to send `BOOL` as input object of the method `setEnabled:`. When I add `NO`, it is not throwing me any error and is working as expected but when I try to use `YES`, its throwing me the error *Incompatible integer to pointer conversion*. Why this partiality :P

BTW it is not even working for `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`. How could I make this work for both `YES` & `NO`.

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:NO];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:YES];
```

Comment: NO is not an object. you have to put that into an NSNumber and then it should work, does so at least on my system.

Comment: @Volker This will not work since both `@YES` and `@NO` will be casted to booleans and evaluated ultimately as `YES` on `setEnabled:`. Having said that, this would indeed work if the method being called could unwrap the value to a bool (by an override or a custom method). [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904515/how-to-use-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-primitive-types-in-cocoa)

Comment: `nil` = `0x00000000` = `0` = `NO`; btw, you cannot send _primitives_ like you tried in your snippet; the `...withObject:` suggests you gently, you can pass _object_ only not _primitives_.

Answer (score -1):

First, your method `setEnabled:` should have an `NSNumber` as param:

```
- (void) setEnabled:(NSNumber*)param {

}
```

Then you could do:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:@NO];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:@YES];
```

About the error: *Incompatible integer to pointer conversion*. `YES` is equal to 1 and the system is not able to convert that value to a pointer value. However, as @holex says `NO` is equal to nil = 0x00000000 = 0 = NO.

Comment: `setEnabled:` is a method on `UIBarButtonItem`. It can work with `BOOL` parameter, just using `[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:@NO];`