# Invoking a private method a second time with inputs of the same type fails to compile

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I have an NS_ENUM defined in a class:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, SIOPredicateType) {
   SIOPredicateTypeEqualTo,
   SIOPredicateTypeNotEqualTo,
   SIOPredicateTypeGreaterThan,
   SIOPredicateTypeGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
   SIOPredicateTypeLessThan,
   SIOPredicateTypeLessThanOrEqualTo,
};
```

Which is used in a private method of the class:

```
- (NSPredicate *) generatePredicateForType: (SIOPredicateType) predicateType withArguments: (NSArray *) arguments {

NSString * operand;

switch (predicateType) {

    case SIOPredicateTypeEqualTo: {
        operand = @"==";
        break;
    }

    case SIOPredicateTypeNotEqualTo: {
        operand = @"!=";
        break;
    }

    case SIOPredicateTypeGreaterThan: {
        operand = @">";
        break;
    }

    case SIOPredicateTypeGreaterThanOrEqualTo: {
        operand = @">=";
        break;
    }

    case SIOPredicateTypeLessThan: {
        operand = @"<";
        break;
    }

    case SIOPredicateTypeLessThanOrEqualTo: {
        operand = @"<=";
        break;
    }

    default: {
        [NSException raise: SIOQueryExceptionInvalidPredicateType format:@"An invalid predicate type was passed to this method."];
        break;
    }

}

    NSString * predicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"key %@ value", operand];

    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateFormat argumentArray: arguments];
}
```

I'm unit testing the private method (No opinions on this practice in this post, please) like so:

```
NSPredicate * testEqualToPredicate =  [testQuery performSelector: @selector(generatePredicateForType:withArguments:)
                                                      withObject: SIOPredicateTypeEqualTo
                                                      withObject:  @[]];

NSPredicate * testNotEqualToPredicate =  [testQuery performSelector: @selector(generatePredicateForType:withArguments:)
                                                      withObject: SIOPredicateTypeNotEqualTo
                                                      withObject:  @[]];
```

My issue is that the first message is sent successfully, but the second one fails with an implicit conversion error. My question is why it would fail on the second one but not the first one. If I invoke the first method by itself, the test passes. If I add another method invocation (Even with a different `SIOPredicateType`) it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is subtle. Neither really works since you can't pass an `NSUInteger` value (your `enum` type) to the `withObject:` parameter.

When you define an enum, each enum value is given the next integer value starting with `0`. This means that the `SIOPredicateTypeEqualTo` enum value has a value of `0`.

So the first call is really compiled as:

```
NSPredicate * testEqualToPredicate =  [testQuery performSelector: @selector(generatePredicateForType:withArguments:)
                                                  withObject:0
                                                  withObject:@[]];
```

An object pointer with a value of `0` is the same as `nil`. So you are really compiling:

```
NSPredicate * testEqualToPredicate =  [testQuery performSelector: @selector(generatePredicateForType:withArguments:)
                                                  withObject:nil
                                                  withObject:@[]];
```

This is why it compiles.

At runtime the `nil` value gets interpreted as a `0` in your `generatePredicateForType:withArguments:` method for 1st argument. This leads to the call to the method working but only for this special case.

The second attempt with the enum value of `SIOPredicateTypeNotEqualTo` correctly fails to compile because you are passing a non-zero `NSUInteger` value to an argument expecting an `id` (object reference) parameter value.

Comment: And for the followup question "Then what's the right way to do it?", see [How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with primitive types in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/904515)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! This was helpful, and makes sense given the implicit conversion warning error I was getting.